# Fields_for for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

Here is my nested resource

```
  resources :hotels do
    resources :roomtype, :reservations
  end
```

What I would like to do is to list room types on the reservation form and determine the amount of rooms I wish to book. I have tried accept_nested_attributes_for to no avail. I can't seem to succeed to create proper a working fields_for form within the reservation form.

specs: rails 4.1, ruby 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 4 uses strong params. Update your model_params method of your Controller to accept nested attributes. Here is a [good explanation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Was trying to figure it out for hours :)